# Add dimension between two elements that are not inside the family editor?

Tags: revit-api

I've seen examples using the NewDimension method to dimension between two points and two lines, I assume in the family editor, but I want to add a dimension to two family instances in the model, such as a pipe tap's centerline and a pipe end. Then the dimension would 'drive' the distance if the user edits it, moving the outlet along the pipe, just like it does if a user created the dimension using the Revit UI.

I just don't know what way Revit wants me to try to do this:

1. Finding the family instance ID, going into each family ID, and finding a line/plane/point in the family to use as a dimension point when you use NewDimension. Hopefully this would work outside the family editor trying to make a dimension between two different family instances (pipe end and pipe tap).
2. Finding the x,y,z location of the points you want to snap to, and creating a dimension (using NewDimension method for example) between those two x,y,z locations, and if the x,y,z locations fall on appropriate points like a pipe end and center-line of a pipe tap then perhaps Revit automatically makes it a 'smart' dimension that 'drives' the location of the pipe tap.

Here's some promising methods I found in the API, not sure which of them I should be using though.

NewDimension
AlignedDimension
AddListeningDimensionBendToBend
AddListeningDimensionSegmentToBend
AddListeningDimensionSegmentToSegment
SetElementsToDimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the two Building Coder samples showing how to [Dimension Walls by Iterating Faces](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/02/dimension-walls-by-iterating-faces.html) and [Dimension Walls using FindReferencesByDirection](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/02/dimension-walls-using-findreferencesbydirection.html).

The approach used for walls works with standard family instances as well.

Note that the `FindReferencesByDirection` method has now been replaced by the [`ReferenceIntersector class](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2018.1/36f82b40-1065-2305-e260-18fc618e756f.htm).